# How to Upload image with some field?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am trying to upload image with some required field like name, description. When i am inserting data without the image field it works, but when trying to upload the image file as well its not inserting data to database. Could anyone tell me what may be wrong with my code?

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'cat_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|min:6',
        'cat_pic' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    $fileName = null;

    if ($request()->hasFile('cat_pic')) {

       $file = $request()->file('cat_pic');
       $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/products/cats/');
       $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);  
       $this->save();
   }

    Catagories::create([
        'cat_name' => $request->input('cat_name'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'cat_pic' => $fileName,

    ]);

    Session::flash('alert', __('messages.created'));
    Session::flash('alertClass', 'success');
    return redirect()->route('catagories');
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-4 offset-5">
<div class="form-group">
    <form role="form" action="<?php echo e('/products/cats') ?>" method="POST" id="createcat" >
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <p>
        Create New Product Category
      </p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_name">
          Name*:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
          id="cat_name" name="cat_name" required maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cat_pic">Category Image* </label>
    <input data-preview="#preview" class="form-control" name="cat_pic" type="file" id="cat_pic">
    <img class="col-md-6" id="preview" height="100px" width="20px" src="">
  </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">
              Description*:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="description"
              id="description" placeholder="Category Description"
              maxlength="600" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btncreatecat">Create</button>

          </form>
      </div>
    </div>

@endsection
@push('scripts')
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#cat_pic").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('products/cats', 'Admin\CatController');
```

and some JQuery to preview the image

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#cat_pic").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your `cat_pic` input is `required` in validation, how you can inserting data without image field ? And your `cat_pic` column in database accept NULL value ? By default, it's not !

Comment: your first question => when i insert other data without the image field(i.e. comment the function); then its works fine but i want to add the image field and need to insert to the database..can you help me?

Comment: Can you add full HTML form ?

Comment: yes i did please check it ..

Comment: Why you not using route name in action instead direct URL. Ex : `<form role="form" action="{{route('post_route_name)}}"`

Comment: Doesn't matter . In laravel store function in controller works for one controller routie

Comment: Nope, check your request with `dd($request)` to ensure your route work fine

Comment: #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#215 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#217 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:4 [▼
      "_token" => "01IG3W2X4GzRwWzpMoWFyNWcxAYWERpiXUlgCTxA"
      "cat_name" => "Default Category"
      "cat_pic" => "Screenshot from 2019-06-13 16-53-43.png"
      "description" => "rhggfertyt"
    ]
  }
  +query: ParameterBag {#51 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#47 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#48 ▼
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}

Comment: do you think its working ?

Comment: Yup, it's working. Next step, check your `$filename` variable before ` Catagories::create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` tag.

Like this:

```
<form role="#" action="#" method="#" id="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

So your form can send other things than text.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem is I just forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside the form tag.